# How I affect another file with code from one?

Tags: java, swing, oop, netbeans

In NetBeans 8.0, I made a **Paint** Program and I needed the code from my main file to affect something in my other file, an interface file. How can I do this? My code:

```
package paintapp;


import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class PaintApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int colourR, colourG, colourB;
    static String Ccolour = "BLACK";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame main = new JFrame("Tessellating Pi - Paint");
        PaintInterface pi = new PaintInterface();
        main.add(pi);
        main.setSize(1000, 1000);
        main.setVisible(true);
        JFrame j = new JFrame("Colour Chooser");
        JButton c = new JButton("Change Colour");
        j.add(c);
        j.setSize(150, 100);
        j.setVisible(true);
        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if ("BLACK".equals(Ccolour)) {
                    Ccolour = "RED";
                    //code to change code in interface to set colour to red
                }
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

This is the Interface:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintInterface extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    static int x = 0, y = 0;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 3, 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

I need to transmit the message to the Interface that I changed the colour. How do I do this? Is there an alternative method of doing this?

Comment: `..extends JPanel .. @Override .. public void paint (Graphics g) {` For Swing components, override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`.  When overriding either, 1st call the super method to paint BG and border, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

1. create a setter method to set the new color.
2. call `repaint` to update the you shape.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might like to have a read of [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), then remove the `addMouseMotionListener`, `addMouseListener` and `setBackground` from your `paint` method (and use `paintComponent`) instead.

Next, you need to decide the best way for you to handle the color management, for example, you could simply use `setForeground` on the `JPanel` and adjust the `Graphics` color when you paint...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("BLACK".equals(Ccolour)){
        Ccolour="RED";
        pi.setForeground(Color.RED);
        pi.repaint();
    }

}
```

This means that `pi` is going to need to become an instance variable or `final`...

```
final PaintInterface pi=new PaintInterface();
```

Then in your `PaintInterface` class, you would need to update the `paintComponent` method

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(getForeground());
    g.fillRect(x,y,3,3);

}
```

I would also discourage you from creating your whole application in the `main` method, apart from [initi thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) issues, you run into all sorts of issues with `static` references and re-usability...